# How to add description below ListTile Widget in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using Wordpair class to generate random words in flutter.
I have this widget

```
Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair){
return ListTile(
  title: Text(
    pair.first,
    //pair.asCamelCase,
    style: _biggerFont,

    ),

);
```

}

How do I add another text widget to describe these words below ListTile widget?

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair){
return ListTile(
  title: Text(
    pair.first,
    //pair.asCamelCase,
    style: _biggerFont,
    ),
  subtitle: Text("description goes here")
);
```

Assuming `pair` contains the word and description, you have

`subtitle: Text(pair.second)`

**NOTE:** this assumes the description is shown just below the text inside the `ListTile` and is very brief to avoid overflow.

Comment: I am now trying to use translator package:
        subtitle:  Text(translator.translate(pair.first,to:'ru');),
But I am unable to do so.. Can you help me how to achieve this?